# Overwrite Controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to overwrite a controller during run-time in Angular 1.4.

I'm working with Angular and Webpack and my ultimate goal is to be able to reload a controller with HMR (hot module replacement). However, my roadblock right now is figuring out how to have the controller update properly.

So in the end if you'd had

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', function() {
  this.message = 'Hello World!';
});
```

Then you modified your controller while the webpack-dev-server is running to:

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', function() {
  this.message = 'Goodbye World!';
});
```

The controller within the current state should update appropriately. I do have logic already in place to reload the state ($state.transitionTo)

I am using UI router and Babel, although Babel should be fairly irrelevant since I'm not using half of the benefits (i.e. classes).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Now when you say 'hot-module-replacement', do you mean watching? Or are you expecting other controllers to have their state remain?

Comment: what exactly is the goal here?  This doesn't look like something that even has a practical use.  A real world use case might make it easier to understand what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you don't know what HMR is you won't see a use. It relies on injecting and overriding javascript to give the effect.

Comment: Simply 'replacing' the controller will nuke all your bindings and leave your markup with nothing to bind to. In the past I have implemented this sort of thing with pure directives. It wasn't super elegant but gave me the control to entirely `$destroy` the isolate scope and replace the html. I used `$compile` to bind a new run-time defined scope to the new run-time defined html template. If this sounds like a direction you might like to go I can detail the approach in an answer.

Comment: Oh wow that sounds terrible. Thanks for the heads up. Argghhv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the rest of your project is setup, but presumably your webpack config has a single entry point. Therefore it makes sense to import your controllers / services etc into that entry point sort of like an index.

Controller:

```
// Main.js

export default function HomeController () {
  this.message = 'Hello World!'
}
```

Index:

```
// entry.js

import angular from 'angular'
import HomeController from './controllers/HomeController.js'

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController)
```

My controller changes seem to be updating correctly in this starter project I made https://github.com/alex-wilmer/app-starter/tree/angular, though it's not HMR, just live reloading.

Comment: The only reason I don't like this approach is that you are forced to specify your controller outside of your controller file and you have to inject the dependencies via $inject.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for y'all that are interested. To make HMR work with controllers in angular, effectively rewriting the body of the controller function, i bound an init function to a long-lasting JavaScript object that is outside the module (aka file).

```
var mod = angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', function($interval) {
    mod.initHomeController(this, $interval);
});

mod.initHomeController = function(vm, $interval) {
    vm.message = 'Hello World!';
};
```